# How can I make a bunch of vertical sliders in swiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, slider, swiftui

I am trying to make a group (10 in the test code, but 32 in reality) of vertical faders using SwiftUI on an iPad app. 
When making sliders horizontally, they stretch across the screen properly. When rotating those same sliders vertical, they seem locked into their horizontal dimensions. Is there a simple way to get the sliders to be vertical?

Horizontal (stretches across screen):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sliderVal: Double = 0
    @State var values: [Double] = Array.init(repeating: 0.0, count: 10)

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            ForEach((0 ... 9), id: \.self) {i in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(i): ")
                    Slider(value: self.$values[i], in: 0 ... 100, step: 1.0)
                        .colorScheme(.dark)
                    Text("\(Int(self.values[i]))")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Switching the stack views and rotating the sliders (does not work):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sliderVal: Double = 0
    @State var values: [Double] = Array.init(repeating: 0.0, count: 10)

    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            ForEach((0 ... 9), id: \.self) {i in
                VStack {
                    Text("\(i): ")
                    Slider(value: self.$values[i], in: 0 ... 100, step: 1.0)
                        .colorScheme(.dark)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                    Text("\(Int(self.values[i]))")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem with rotating Sliders, and finally gave up and just made my own VSlider struct. I'll see if I can find my example code and post an answer.

Answer (score 12):

I made a custom VSlider view ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/john-mueller/SwiftUI-Examples/tree/master/SwiftUI-Examples/VSlider)) to address this issue. It should be virtually identical in usage to a Slider, as shown in the comparison demo below (although it's not generic, so it has to be used with a Double).

[image: VSlider demo]

Comment: Your sliders are nice and tidy and work very much like what you'd expect from a native vertical slider. Thanks for putting it out there; this answer should gain more visibility :)

Comment: Thanks! Just required one minor change to work on MacOS (MacOS doesn't have .systemGray4.)

Comment: This is great and should have way more love! thanks

Answer (score 12):

You can make vertical sliders from horizontal ones in SwiftUI, the trick is frame(width:) and frame(height:) are swapped. Here is what I did to make some really nice vertical sliders using the built-in SwiftUI functions

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct VerticalSlider: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var playData : PlayData
    var channelNumber:Int
    var sliderHeight:CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        Slider(
            value: self.$playData.flickerDimmerValues[self.channelNumber],
            in: 0...255,
            step: 5.0
        ).rotationEffect(.degrees(-90.0), anchor: .topLeading)
        .frame(width: sliderHeight)
        .offset(y: sliderHeight)
    }
}
```

Then pass the Slider frame(width: ) to the above code in the variable ***sliderHeight*** as in the following code, where ***sliderHeight*** is the layout dimension provided by SwiftUI when it is laying out the view. This is a slick use of GeometryReader to size the slider exactly right.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct VerticalBar: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var playData : PlayData
    var channelNumber:Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                VerticalSlider(
                    channelNumber: self.channelNumber,
                    sliderHeight: geo.size.height
                )
            }
            Text("\(self.channelNumber + 1)")
                .font(.headline)
                .frame(height: 10.0)
                .padding(.bottom)
           
        }
    }
}
```

I then put 8 of the above views within a view area using a HStack:

```swift
HStack {
    Spacer(minLength: 5.0)
    VerticalBar(channelNumber: 0)
    VerticalBar(channelNumber: 1)
    VerticalBar(channelNumber: 2)
    VerticalBar(channelNumber: 3)
    VerticalBar(channelNumber: 4)
    VerticalBar(channelNumber: 5)
    VerticalBar(channelNumber: 6)
    VerticalBar(channelNumber: 7)
    Spacer(minLength: 5.0)
}
```

When completed, the vertical sliders look like this:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore.  The sliders appear to be in a box with the height and width the same.

Answer (score 0):

There's this SwiftUI library I found: [link to repo](https://github.com/spacenation/swiftui-sliders). The nice thing about it is that the sliders are the same across macOS and other platforms. Also, you can customize the slider very easily.